# Make combo boxes exclusive/precise in generating data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with 7 combo boxes that are used to search data from the worksheet. I intend to present column 6(mass) and 8(index) as ranges i.e. for mass: 0.007-0.1; 0.11-2.5; 0.251-0.5 etc. The other 5 combo boxes are just absolute values (not range).I'm attempting to loop through the cells in the data sheet(shD) and whenever the row matches matches all selections made on the userform; then the entire row is copied to the results sheet(shR). The user may leave some of the combo boxes blank, but they should still be able to get results. What the code is doing now is may be say in the time combobox(cbInj) I selected say 15 seconds; the code will include 20 seconds which does not match the 15sec on the combo box. Here is my code;

```
'combo boxes variable definition, in order to compact and make the code easy to be understood:
    Set cbPr = User_search.Cbx_Project_code
    Set cbTr = User_search.Cbx_TrueNOC
    Set cbDn = User_search.Cbx_DNAmass
    Set cbK = User_search.Cbx_Kit
    Set cbQ = User_search.Cbx_QIndex
    Set cbInj = User_search.Cbx_Injection_time
    Set cbInstr = User_search.Cbx_Instrument  

    'Check selection for mass and present it as a range
    If Len(cbDn.Value) > 0 Then
        arrDn = Split(cbDn.Value, "-")
        mnDn = CDbl(arrDn(0))
        mxDn = CDbl(arrDn(1))
    End If

    'checkfor Index if selected and present it as a range
    If Len(cbQ.Value) > 0 Then
        arrQ = Split(cbQ.Value, "-")
        mnQ = CVar(arrQ(0))
        mxQ = CVar(arrQ(1))
    End If

        'count the total rows on Data
         totD = shD.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of "Data" sheet

        For i = 5 To totD
            vDn = shD.Cells(i, 6).Value
            vQ = shD.Cells(i, 8).Value
            If (Trim(shD.Cells(i, 2)) = Trim(cbPr.Value) Or cbPr.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(shD.Cells(i, 5)) = Trim(cbTr.Value) Or cbTr.Value = "") And _
            vDn > mnDn And vDn <= mxDn Or cbDn.Value = "" And _
            (Trim(shD.Cells(i, 7)) = Trim(cbK.Value) Or cbK.Value = "") And _
            vQ > mnQ And vQ <= mxQ Or cbQ.Value = "" And _
            (Trim(shD.Cells(i, 9)) = Trim(cbInj.Value) Or cbInj.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(shD.Cells(i, 10)) = Trim(cbInstr.Value) Or cbInstr.Value = "") Then

            totR = shR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            shD.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shR.Cells(totR + 1, 1)
    End If

   Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight logic problem in your "range" tests - eg:

```
vQ > mnQ And vQ <= mxQ Or cbQ.Value = "" And _
```

should be

```
((vQ > mnQ And vQ <= mxQ) Or cbQ.Value = "") And _
```

I would do something like this.  Individual tests are faster, since there's no need to continue checking after any failed test

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim cbPr, cbTr, cbDn, cbk, cbQ, cbInj, cbInstr 'all variants
    Dim rw As Range, isMatch As Boolean, arrCrit

    'get combo boxes values
    cbPr = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Project_code.Value)
    cbTr = Trim(User_search.Cbx_TrueNOC.Value)
    cbDn = Trim(User_search.Cbx_DNAmass.Value)
    If Len(cbDn) > 0 Then cbDn = Split(cbDn, "-") 'convert to array
    cbk = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Kit.Value)
    cbQ = Trim(User_search.Cbx_QIndex.Value)
    If Len(cbQ) > 0 Then cbDn = Split(cbQ, "-")   'convert to array
    cbInj = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Injection_time.Value)
    cbInstr = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Instrument.Value)

    arrCrit = Array(2, cbPr, 5, cbTr, 6, cbDn, 7, cbk, 8, cbQ, 9, cbInj, 10, cbInstr)
    
    For i = 5 To shD.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rw = shD.Rows(i)
        For n = LBound(arrCrit) To UBound(arrCrit) - 1 Step 2
            isMatch = CellIsMatch(rw.Cells(arrCrit(n)), arrCrit(n + 1))
            If Not isMatch Then Exit For
        Next n
        If isMatch Then rw.Copy shR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
    
End Sub

'Does a cell value match the supplied criteria?
'  Criteria could be a range of two numeric values
Function CellIsMatch(cell As Range, crit) As Boolean
    Dim v
    v = cell.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        'is the criteria an array (range) ?
        If TypeName(crit) Like "*()" Then
            'assumes v is numeric
            CellIsMatch = (v > CDbl(Trim(crit(0))) And _
                           v < CDbl(Trim(crit(1))))
        Else
            CellIsMatch = (Trim(v) = crit) Or Len(crit) = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. This one seems to work, but there is a tiny problem. It only recognizes one part of the data. I have two types of samples RD12 and RD14. The code works exceptionally well to bring back results for RD14 samples whatever the combination one chooses. But with the 2nd sample (RD12); no results are given back whatever the selection in the userform. This is surprising because the naming and number of characters is similar between these samples.

Comment: I can't see your data, so it's difficult for me to guess what the problem might be.  Unless you can share your workbook I'm not sure what to suggest.